# Angular Unit-testing NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[MatSnackBarComponent -> MatSnackBarComponent]:

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

In my MainComponent I have entryComponent MatSnackBarComponent(custom component).
When I'm writing tests i get this Error:

NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[MatSnackBarComponent -> MatSnackBarComponent]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSnackBarComponent!

```
describe('MainComponent', () => {
  let component: MainComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MainComponent>;
  let orderService: OrderService;

  const fakeMatDialogRef = jasmine.createSpyObj(['close']);

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot()
      ],
      declarations: [MainComponent],
      providers: [
        OrderService,
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: fakeMatDialogRef }, 
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} }
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved. Need to add code below to providers

```
{ provide: MatSnackBarComponent, useValue: {} }
```

Comment: Yes, or create a `MatSnackBarMockComponent` in your specfile, with a `useClass`. Add the `@Input`s and `@Output`s you have used in the unit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ***MatSnackBarModule***  module in your imports.

```
imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        MatSnackBarModule, //<---Added MatSnackBarModule
        TranslateModule.forRoot()
],
```

Comment: Is it still having that issue after you added the MatSnackBarModule in your import?

Comment: MatSnackBarComponent doesn’t added in my test, but I’ve tried different ways… Maybe I need to mock it somehow

Comment: So you are using MatSnackBarComponent in your MainComponent? Did you add MatSnackBarModule in your MainModule and not in the app.module.ts?

Comment: I didnt add MatSnackBarModule anywhere. Only MatSnackBar in MatSnackBarComponent